# Is it possible to use output_file instead of show_in_notebook when displaying LIME explanation results?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python and I have just discovered LIME for model prediction interpretation, I have followed code from this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/emanceau/interpreting-machine-learning-lime-explainer

I am wondering if there is a way of displaying the explanations as they are shown in Jupyter notebook without using notebook, i.e running python on a text editor. I have seen something about output_file but I can't figure out how to implement it with lime. I am hoping to see something like what is shown in notebook:

[show_in_notebook img](https://images.app.goo.gl/ZRP2tv9PXDtBxKcx6)

Is this possible, or do I need to start using Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need to start a jupyter notebook to display the explanations as they are shown with the help of `show_in_notebook` function.

LIME package provides `save_to_file` function that allows one to save explanations to .html pages. In a python script it would be something like this:

`explainer=lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X.values,feature_names=X.columns)
exp = explainer.explain_instance(data_for_prediction, model.predict_proba)
exp.save_to_file('lime.html')`

There's also `as_pyplot_figure` that creates a barchart explaining the prediction. The output can be saved with `matplotlib.savefig`.